# strip() works selectively on the input function but properly on a string literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I am trying to understand the `strip()` function. And I'm seeing a confusing behavior.

```
import sys
test = input().strip('e')
print(test)

N = input().strip('cmowz.')
print(N)

print('www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.'))
```

This gives the following output:

```
test   message  here   
'www.example.com'
example
```

So what I'm seeing is that calling `input().strip()` method works properly for trailing and leading spaces. But it doesn't work for anything else.

`input().strip('e')` doesn't really strip e from the string.

However, calling a string literal `"somethinghere".strip('e')` works fine.

Can someone please explain this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: I can't recreate this; `N = input().strip('cmowz.')` outputs `'example'` for me.

Comment: Works [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) - _return a copy of the string **with the leading and trailing characters** removed_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with `leading` and `trailing` characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on.

This is working exactly as expected.

Comment: This makes sense. Basically in the first case I'm inputting "     some text    " so no changes happen here because cmoz. aren't part of the whitespaces. However, In the second case I was inputting the string along with the single quotes that's why I was seeing a weird output. I tried inputting without the single quotes and it works fine. Marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

> string.strip(s[, chars]) Return a copy of the string with leading and
>   trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string;
>   the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of
>   the string this method is called on.
>
> Changed in version 2.2.3: The chars parameter was added. The chars
>   parameter cannot be passed in earlier 2.2 versions.

The important part is, that only trailing and leading characters are removed.